# ROS Answers SE migration: Bent robot

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Another way to put the question: what makes the robot stand? and what makes it bent? I cannot attach a picture since my karma is below 60 but I hope that my question is clear.
Thanks

I have two identical environments running exactly the same drcsim (1.0.3): one where the robot stands and one where the robot is bent. (See attached picture)
I don't know what makes the robot be bent. Can you help me?
I lost my eyesight trying to find the difference between the two environments without success.
Thanks for enlightening me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/251/bent-robot/) by [mhallak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/93/mhallak/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 96 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2012-11-20**:
what launch file did you use to start the worlds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I suspect that the difference is due to exactly when the position-holding controllers were engaged with respect to when simulation started.  To avoid this kind of difference, later versions of drcsim use a 10-second (simulated) delay before applying gravity to the Atlas model.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0